# Filter model on reverse_set length

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Consider these pseudo classes:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

I would like to filter via Foo's manager effectively to get a QuerySet that only holds Foo objects with atleast 2 Bar objects pointing towards it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) with `Count`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Foo.objects.annotate(bar_count=Count('bar')).filter(bar_count__gte=2)
```

Comment: Great thanks, I was playing with annotate but I passed double underscores